# The role of asterisk(*) in front of function literal type in go langauge

Tags: go

How is the last line of next go code snippet understood?
I could't find any references for (*functionLiteralType)(nil) format expression.

```
type QInterface interface {
    apply(int) string
}

type flType func(int) string
func (c flType) apply(i int) string {
    return c(i)
}

var _ QInterface = (*flType)(nil)
```

Comment: It is to ensure that the type `flType` implements `QInterface`

Comment: @SarathSadasivanPillai not quite -- it ensures that the type `*flType` implements `QInterface`.

Comment: That's not a function literal. It's a type name.

Comment: See https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#blank_implements

Answer (score 0):

That is a way to generally ensure that a type implements an interface at compile time. Following examples does the same

```
type A string
type B int

func (a A) apply(i int) string {
    return fmt.Sprint(a)
}

func (b B) apply(i int) string {
    return fmt.Sprint(b)
}

 var _ QInterface = (*A)(nil)
var _ QInterface = (*B)(nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

`*T` is a pointer type. https://go.dev/ref/spec#Pointer_types. `*flType` is a type that's a pointer to things of `flType` (which has underlying type `func(int) string`). There's no such thing as a "function literal type".

`T(x)` is a type conversion of `x` to the type `T`. Here, `T` is the type `*flType` and `x` is nil, so it converts the `nil` to the given pointer type. Brackets are needed around the type because of precendence, so it's written `(*flType)(nil)`.

Finally, you're assigning this value to a variable (or more accurately here the blank identifier) of type `QInterface`. For this to compile, the value must be assignable to `QInterface`, which in this case means values of type `*flType` must implement the interface `QInterface`.

Comment: Thanks. It's so helpful. By the way, why is it (*flType)(nil) instead of (flType)? Just like C/C++, are those the same one?